# Taking password from a file while SSH ing into a machine

Tags: ssh, input

I want to SSH into a remote machine but instead of typing the password, I want to redirect it from another file.

So I have a file `password.txt` that stores the password. `File.sh` is my bash file.

In `File.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -T user@10.2.5.1
```

While executing the file, I did:

```
./File.sh < password.txt
```

But I was asked to enter password anyway.

How do I get the password to be input from the file?

Comment: You might want to read this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340366/how-to-make-ssh-receive-the-password-from-stdin

Comment: Have you considered "ssh public key authentication"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SSH with 'password in a file' is commonly used as public key authentication. Create a key pair using `ssh-keygen`, upload the public key to the other host:

```
scp ./.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@10.2.5.1:~/
```

and place it as `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`:

```
ssh user@10.2.5.1
mkdir ~/.ssh
mv ~/id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

or, if an `authorized_keys` file already exists:

```
cat ~/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

set the appropriate permissions (600 for the file, 700 for the directory):

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

and start a new ssh session.

Comment: Hello, I suggested an edit that appends to `authorized_keys` instead of overwriting it if it already exists.

Comment: This doesn't precisely answers the question imho, he asked for a password clearly stored in a txt

Answer (score 8):

You can use `sshpass` to do that:

```
sshpass -f password.txt ssh -T user@10.2.5.1
```

Comment: Does sshpass require superuser privileges? Because it says command not found for me.

Comment: No. It does not. But you have to install it before trying to run it. It is not clear what your OS is.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh shw@hostname
expect -exact "shw@hostname's password: "
send -- "PASSWORD\r"
expect "$ "
interact
```

Expect is a tool to automate the process.

Comment: Do all these commands need superuser privileges? Because this code wasn't executing.